# Fetching data using Rfacebook - error

Tags: r, web-scraping

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="app_id", app_secret="app_secret")

Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/ 
When done, press any key to continue...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
```

I am getting this error. As you see authentication is complete. Any way to solve this ?